# Why is "taxa" the plural form of "taxon"?

Tags: suffixes

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation), taxon is a back-formation from taxonomy, meaning that the *n* in the taxon comes from the suffix *nomy*, so why the heck is the plural of *taxon* -- *taxa*? Are scientists thinking that the *-on* is a Greek suffix that turns to *-a* in plural?

Comment: If they can create 'taxon' as a back-formation from 'taxonomy', what's to stop them creating 'taxa' as a back-back-formation? They'll be cloning sheep next.

Comment: Since Etymonline says it's from German you're lucky it's not Taxone or Taxonen

Comment: "First recorded in 1945–50; from Greek táx(is) “arranged, put in order” + -on neuter noun ending; see taxis1, -on1."

Comment: Perhaps it’s Anglo-Taxon.

Comment: @JohnLawler, what is the source?

Comment: Google is where I found it. It's just a Scientific Greek word.

Comment: Modeled on *ad astra*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working from the example in the OED

> "In order to simplify the wording of the Rules, it is proposed to indicate a taxonomic group of any rank with the term taxon (plural taxa)."

The plural of taxon as "taxa" was proposed by [Dr. Herman Johannes Lam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Johannes_Lam), a Dutch botanist, in the summer of 1948 at the Utrecht Conference on Botanical Nomenclature. His suggestion was accepted. The minutes of the conference are available in the 14th of June 1950 edition of the *Chronica Botanica*.

From Google Books:

[The Prehistory and History of IAPT](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1221116) by FA Stafleu · 1988 ·

> Lam proposed to the Utrecht Conference to use this term for "taxonomic group" and the Conference of 1948 as well as the Stockholm Congress accepted [this].

Comment: This works so well because _-on_ was a regular Greek neuter singular nominative/accusative  ending, and _-a_ was the regular neuter plural n/a ending in both Latin and Greek. And all biologists know that.